# Staxon - getting rid of $ and @ in JSON tag names

Tags: json, xml

In Staxon the following XML

```
<Error data="Something">blah blah blah</Error>
```

gets converted to:

*"Error" : {
                "@data" : "Something",
                "$" : "blah blah blah"
            }*

Yet almost every converter like org.json.XML and OxygenXML would convert that to:

*"Error" : {
                "data" : "Something",
                "content" : "blah blah blah"
            }*

ie it would string the @ from attributes and the $ would be 'content'. Is there anything I can do to get it to be consistent (talking about various large xml documents so specifying every node would be hard)?

Comment: There is absolutely no standard for XML-to-JSON conversion, and every conversion scheme has strengths and weaknesses. Most converters offer very little in the way of customisation capability. Choose a converter whose output you like; or transform the XML prior to conversion; or transform the JSON after conversion.